# json.parse gives Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token (Django json serialized queryset)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, json

I am experiencing the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token` when trying to parse the json data

This is my ajax code (json2.js):

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/best_choose/invoice/item_search.json/',
            data: jsonQuery,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

            success: function(data){
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
                    //do stuff
             }});
```

my view:

```
    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer('json')()
    serialized_q = json_serializer.serialize(queryset, ensure_ascii=False)

    return HttpResponse(
                serialized_q, mimetype='application/json'
            )
```

from debug serialized_q is a unicode string containing valid json `u'valid_json'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you set `dataType` to `json`, jQuery parses the data for you. So you don't need to put it through `JSON.parse`, you can just refer to `data` as a normal Javascript object.